# Why is there no execution time difference between multithreading and singlethreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.4

I am trying to learn python language and it's concept. I wrote some code to play with multithreading. But i notice that there is no execution time difference between multi and single threading.

The machine which is to run script has 4 core/thread.

```
 def get_tokens(file_name,map):
    print(file_name)
    counter = 0
    with open(file_name,'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        for line in f:
            item = json.loads(line,encoding='utf-8')
            if 'spot' in item and item['sid'] == 4663:
                counter+=1
                if counter == 500:
                    break
                tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(item['spot'],language='english')
                for token in tokens:
                    if token not in map:
                        map[token] = 1
                    else:
                        map[token] = map[token] + 1;

 start_time = time.time()
 map = dict();
 with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for file in FileProcessing.get_files_in_directory('D:\\Raw Data'):
        future = executor.submit(FileProcessing.get_tokens, file, map)

 end_time = time.time()
 print("Elapsed time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))
```

Each file's size in the **Raw Data** is bigger than 25 mb. So i think must be difference between them. But there is not. Why ? Am i doing a mistake in code or multihreading concept ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPython (the standard implementation of Python) does not support multithreading on different CPUs. So you can indeed have multiple threads, but they will all run on the same CPU, and you will not have speed improvements for CPU-bound processes (you would have for I/O bound processes).

The reason for that is the infamous GIL (global interpreter lock). Python's core is not thread safe because of the way it does garbage collection, so it uses a lock, which means threads accessing python objects run one after the other.

In your particular case, you are doing some I/O and some processing. There is significant overhead when doing multiprocessing in python, which is not compensated by the gain in speed in your I/O (the time to read your files is probably small compared to the time to process them).

If you need to do real multithreading look at Cython (not to be confused with CPython) and "no_gil", or c-extensions, or the multiprocessing module.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Python has the [Global Interpretor Lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), that prevents two threads of execution in the same python process from executing at the same time.  Therefore, while python threads give you multiple control paths within a single process those multiple control paths cannot execute simultaneous on a multi-core machine.  An alternative is to use the python [multiprocessing framework](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which will actually create separate processes and then have the processes communicate via inter-process communication (IPC).  You can also try using the [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html) which will spawn multiple processes and therefore you won't have an issue with the GIL

Comment: I read something about multiprocessing packet on python docs. They say that " The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads." And then i tested it, the processes which are created by main process do not work simultaneously. They are more effective than thread but not simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The GIL comments are correct, but this code is more likely IO-bound than CPU-bound.

*Even* if you used something like C or Java, you're still reading files over a serial interface, so unless you can't process 100-300 MB/s of JSON, you won't see a performance benefit from threading.

@DevShark did say you'd see a benefit for IO-bound processes, but it's more complicated than that. That tends to be more for concurrent network connections that are high-latency. In this case, you'd be IO-bound *at the disk*, not the process (you're not waiting for a remote response), so parallelism won't help.

If you're CPU-bound, have real threads, and are using a spinning disk, you still have to tune the buffer sizes carefully. The 10ms seek time can kill you, so you need to use buffered reads with buffer sizes much larger than that if you want high disk throughput. With a 100MB/s disk with 10ms seek time, I'd use 10MB buffers, but that still means you're spending 10% of your time seeking on the disk. I'd also coordinate my reads so only one reader reads at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is can the code be improved through threading. If the code is serial and one thing happens after another in a straight line then the code will run the same no matter how many threads you have. However if the code can branch off and do action a and action b at the same time then it will. Looking closer at your code it appears that there is no branching, at least non that I am aware of.

Comment: `executor.submit()` seems to be an attempt to schedule concurrent work.  https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit

Answer (score 1):

Your code is CPU-bound - multithreading will stay within a single CPU by default.  You can use the [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which allows you to create subprocesses and essentially bypass the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock).  Of course, this will only help if you have a multiple CPUs. And I don't think the overhead of multiple processes is warranted for this use case.

Comment: Why would multithreading stay within a single CPU? It will use all available CPUs just serialize their use via GIL so that only a single CPU is in use at a moment